# How do I import from Postman and ensure all of my environment variables will get resolved?

Tags: paw-app

I have a pretty large suite of Postman definitions, and every request contains one or more Postman-style variables, e.g. `{{HOST}}`. The values for those are obviously different for each of my Postman environments. I have successfully imported all of my environments into Paw, and then I imported one of my collections, but none of the variables were converted into Paw-style variables, it seems, because I am having to go to each one and delete the likes of `{{HOST}}` in favor of re-typing from scratch `{HOST}` so that it will resolve to the proper environment variable placeholder. I tried hacking the imported file as well as the importer extension to beat it into submission but to no avail. Is there really no way to get these variables to import as placeholders?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've put an answer below. It should all now be working with our update of the Postman Importer.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Paw has a new documentation article on [How to migrate from Postman to Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/migrate/postman)

---

Probably late for an answer, but we've recently improved the Postman Importer so all variable tags (like `{{variable}}`) are now resolved into environment variables: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/PostmanImporter