# Import dynamic variables from Postman into PAW

Tags: paw-app

I've set up a pretty extensive set of calls in collections using postman. I use dynamic variables (e.g. {{USERNAME}}) in the URL, headers, and body of these calls that are dynamically replaced by variables from my selected postman environment. I'd like to import this collection (along with environments) to PAW and have the dynamic postman variables be switched to dynamic PAW variables.

I've looked at [How do I import from Postman and ensure all of my environment variables will get resolved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33365606/how-do-i-import-from-postman-and-ensure-all-of-my-environment-variables-will-get/34040431#34040431) which is this exact same question, but the answer (to use the Postman Importer - https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/PostmanImporter) doesn't seem to work completely.

I've tried the latest version of the importer (v2.0.0) and while it appears to convert the dynamic variables I define in the headers of my postman calls, it does not replace those in the URL or request body. After importing to PAW I still have, for example, {{USERNAME}} in my request body.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're currently working on a large project that will enable Paw to import many API formats in a lot nicer way (including Postman), we should have something ready by next week, and it will solve the problem you're having for environment variable `{{EXAMPLE}}` in the URL and the body.

Though, I've checked and it appears that the previous version of the Postman Importer had this environment variable import right. So maybe it's worth giving it a try if you need that today: https://github.com/luckymarmot/Paw-PostmanImporter/releases/tag/v1.2.0

All you have to do, is checkout the repo, checkout the tag `v1.2.0` and run `npm install` and `cake install`. It should install itself in the Paw extension directory and replace the existing version of the importer.

Comment: Thanks, Micha! I'll wait a week.

Comment: Micha, any update on this? From sounds of it (many API formats),I assume this would either be a different extension than the PostmanImporter or an integral part of an updated Paw. Can you provide any guidance on what I should be looking for so I'll know when it hits?

Comment: Actually we're doing a massive rewrite of most of our extensions, which will allow better imports. In the meantime, I've set back the previous version of the Postman Importer: go to the Paw menu > Extensions > Check for Extensions Updates… and it should be working now. Lmk if it works :) And sorry for the delay in answering (we're working hard on the next big version of Paw!)

Comment: It didn't find an extension update. I removed the Postman Importer, reinstalled, and reimported my collection with the same results. The URL and body dynamic variables are not switched over to the analogous PAW ones. Not sure how to tell the "version" of the extension, but the files installed show an Apr 14, 2016 date.